# Grant rights to create a table with an identity column on another schema

Tags: oracle, permissions, identity, oracle-19c

I have a user in charge of deploying DDL on other schemas than its own.
This user can create a table on those schemas, it can also create sequences on those schemas.

But when I try to create a table with a GENERATED IDENTITY column on those schemas,
the user encounters an `ORA-01031: privileges insuffisants`

When this user try the same create table on its own schema he can do it properly.

This user was given the following rights :

```sql
GRANT CREATE ANY SEQUENCE TO ddl_role;
GRANT CREATE ANY TABLE TO ddl_role;
```

Here is an example of the query executed :

```sql
CREATE TABLE "sch1"."tab1"
   (        "col1" NUMBER GENERATED BY DEFAULT ON NULL AS IDENTITY MINVALUE 1 INCREMENT BY 1 START WITH 1 CACHE 20 NOORDER  NOCYCLE  NOKEEP  NOSCALE)
TABLESPACE "sch1_data";
```

The following queries work :

```sql
CREATE TABLE "sch1"."tab1"
    (        "col1" NUMBER )
TABLESPACE "sch1_data";

CREATE SEQUENCE "sch1"."seq1";
```

**References :**
https://oracle-base.com/articles/12c/identity-columns-in-oracle-12cr1

Comment: Why do you quote the names? Are sure the table space `"sch1_data"` (in lower case) exist? Do you have permissions on the tablespace? Try `GRANT UNLIMITED TABLESPACE TO ddl_role`

Comment: Tablespace exists and unlimited quota is already given to the user.
Btw I could also unquote the names the problem remains the same.

Comment: Is it possible to modify how this sequence is created ? And wouldn't this cause trouble for other users who don't have access to the creator's schema ?

Comment: Hmmm. Actually there is something else. I just tried the scenario, but I still get a privilege error. So there is something more than just the CREATE SEQUENCE issue. Let me investigate. This is an interesting case.

Comment: Sorry, I was wrong. The sequence DOES get created into the schema of the TABLE (so in "sch1" in your example. But: the creating user must also have the `SELECT ANY SEQUENCE` right. I'm not clear why that is a requirement. (I deleted my other comment)

Comment: Yes I also verified on where the sequence was created it is indeed in the same schema as the table. I will try with SELECT ANY SEQUENCE grant.

Comment: About quoted names: it is better to use unquoted names: that makes them case-insensitive. If you call a table `"tab1`" you are giving it a lower-case name, and all applications will need to use the quoted identifier. Queries like `SELECT ... FROM TAB1` will fail. But so will queries like `select ... from tab1`. The only reason for using quoted identifiers is if you have names with special characters or spaces - like `"SPECIAL TABLE%1"`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to create a table using the `GENERATED BY...` mechanism you need also the `SELECT ANY SEQUENCE` privilege, in addition to `CREATE ANY SEQUENCE`.

I don't know why that is the case, since you are able to create a standalone sequence. I suspect it has to do with setting up the link between the table and the sequence.

Here is an example:

```
SQL> connect pg_test/pg_test@graphdb
Connected.

SQL> select privilege from user_sys_privs;

PRIVILEGE
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
CREATE ANY TABLE
CREATE SESSION
CREATE ANY SEQUENCE
SELECT ANY SEQUENCE
ALTER SESSION

5 rows selected.

SQL> create table scott.t1 (i number GENERATED BY DEFAULT ON NULL AS IDENTITY);
Table created.
```

And in the other schema:

```
SQL> connect scott/tiger@graphdb
Connected.

SQL> select * from cat;

TABLE_NAME                     TABLE_TYPE
------------------------------ ---------------------------------
...
T1                             TABLE
ISEQ$$_81682                   SEQUENCE

50 rows selected.
```

If I revoke the `SELECT ANY SEQUENCE` privilege from user `pg_test` then the table creation will fail.